# AJAX to output XML in aspx page

Tags: c#, ajax, xml, web-services

I have this ajax in my login page, and I reference a checker.aspx that checks if the username and password is valid and returns 0 or 1. How do I return 0 or 1 in xml in my checker page ? Is it possible with AJAX ?

```
function getResult() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("lblMessage").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "checker.aspx?username=" + document.getElementById("txtUserName").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("txtPassword").value, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml"); to return a built XML string from an action.

Comment: I don't undertstand. would I put that line below xmlhttp.send?

Comment: This would be the result of the action on the server side method you are calling from this action.  public ActionResult CheckUser (int userid){ somelogic; return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml"); }

Comment: I am not using MVC , just a basic web form.aspx.

Comment: Not that i can tell. Work for me with the standards using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

Comment: I can't use the namespace using system.web.mvc